# GAE/P: Testbed stub for runtime.memory_usage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've just learned that you can do this in App Engine to get your instance memory usage:

```
from google.appengine.api.runtime import memory_usage
memory_usage().current()
```

This is very cool, but when I run tests, I get this error:

> File
>   ".../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py",
>   line 322, in MakeSyncCall
>       assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "system"

Is there a stub for this in testbed?  There is not a `init_system_stub`.

Comment: I just rant into this after upgrading GAE. Maybe a regression?

Comment: I'm hitting this same exception trying to unittest code that uses the `background_thread` feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [wonky GAE reference guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.runtime.runtime), it looks like `google.appengine.api.runtime` has been deprecated since version 1.8.1. According to [the SDK Release notes](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes), version 1.8.1 is over two years old. Google may have just dropped support for it.

Would have been nice if they spat out a runtime warning first though.

Comment: Is there a non deprecated way to get instance memory usage?